# jQuery function running while loading page instead of clicking on element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Okay, I have a strange problem here. I have below html file where I have included my jquery file - Core.js. Now according to the implementation, when users clicks on Index link, I am to load the result in results div. The problem is the function - fetchRecords() is running on page load of html rather than waiting for a user to click the Index. Can anyone please tell what is the issue here?

Index.cshtml

```
<body>
    <a href="#" id="indexpagelink">Index</a>
    <div id="results"></div>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Core.js")"></script>
</body>
```

Core.js

```
$(function () {

var fetchRecords = function () {

    var $a = $(this);

    var options = {
        url: "/Home/FetchRecords",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "html"
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {

        var $target = $("#results");
        var $newHtml = $(data);
        $target.html($newHtml);
    });

    return false;
};

$("#indexpagelink").on("click", fetchRecords());

});
```

Edit: Also, I need to know if placing the script tag at close of body makes more sense than placing in head tag or not?

Comment: remove the () from `,fetchRecords()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#indexpagelink").on("click", fetchRecords);
```

Remove parenteses. With them - you call the function.

Comment: Oh boy! Have implemented this stuff before, but somehow just missed to find the bug here. Thanks.

Comment: Well, browsers will start downloading and processing your script tags as soon as they see them. So if you put them in the head and load them synchronously then browser will not continue to process the rest of the page untill it downloads and processes those scripts. Modern browsers support asynchronous loading but if you put your scripts in the end of the page then even in the old browsers all the content will be shown to the user before the browser will start working on downloading and processing the scripts, which gives a better user experience.